# Is Spring MVC without Controller Possible (but Using only DispatcherServlet)

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to configure a spring mvc application without writing explicit controllers, but only using DispatcherServlet. I am having tough time getting it working (**I did not add a Controller on purpose**). Here is my code:

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Within a JSP:

```
<a href="/myapp/test1.htm">Test1 HTML</a> &nbsp;
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] WARN  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/test1.htm] in DispatcherServlet
with name 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: That's quite expected. What exactly is your goal here? You mapped *.htm to the dispatcher servlet. You send a request to test1.htm. So it goes to the dispatcher servlet. The dispatcher servlet tries dispatching the request to a controller mapped to /test1.htm, and doesn't find any, since you didn't define any controller at all, so it sends back a 404 error.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Seems silly to me.  Write using the proper idiom.

Comment: My goal is to understand why we need a controller when all i want to do is to send the request to a particular resource. Isn't spring mvc's dispatcher servlet flexible enough to figure out that there is no controller here, and dispatcher servlet should just route the request to test1.htm. If it is flexible enough, then all i want to know is how to do it.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a view controller.

Comment: Map your `DispatcherServlet` to `/` and register a `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in your xml file. This will pass all not resolved URIs to the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by specifying a controller in the dispatcher-servlet.xml, as long as you have also specified some kind of view resolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/htm/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".htm" />
</bean>

<mvc:view-controller path="/test" view-name="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your question is actually to know if it's possible to serve static resources having a name that is matched by the dispatcher-servlet matching.

That is definitely possible, [and documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-default-servlet-handler):

> This allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (thus overriding the mapping of the container’s default Servlet), while still allowing static resource requests to be handled by the container’s default Servlet. It configures a DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler with a URL mapping of "/**" and the lowest priority relative to other URL mappings.
>
> This handler will forward all requests to the default Servlet.

It's quite strange though to choose to map the spring servlet to a very specific mapping (`*.htm`), although you know that this mapping will clash with static resources. You could simply choose to map the servlet to any other extension (`*.action`, or whatever), and thus not have this conflict in the first place.